# How to access the other page session variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables

I have followed this [link](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/) to set and get the session variable. In my rails applications, i can access the other page session variable in development mode. But i can't access the other page session variable in production mode. How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` is, by its very definition, *per session*.  They are not and cannot be shared across pages.

On the other hand, `localStorage` is shared between sessions.